# How to make global "Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(...)" methods

Tags: java, android

I have the same methods in various classes (views) and would like to abstract them somehow so I don't have the identical code parts in multiple classes. How do I have to do this in Android?

The method I have multiple times in my project looks like this:

```
    public void goHome() {
    Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(CurrentClass.this, ClassWhereToGo.class);
    startActivity(explicitIntent);
}
```

In the end I just want to have this one in the whole project and be able to access it dynamically from different views. I guess I have to add two parameters to goHome(p1, p2) in order to be able to access the method from various views. I just don't know where I have to place the method and how I have to make it work with the parameters.

I think ideally I would create some sort of helper class?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Helper
{

    public static void goHome(Context context, Class<?> cls) {
        Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(context, cls);
        context.startActivity(explicitIntent);
    }

}
```

and it would be used like this:

```
Helper.goHome(CurrentClass.this, ClassWhereToGo.class);
```

Comment: If ClassWhereToGo is always the same (I suspect that it is) this can be simplified further. At that point this becomes so simple that I wonder why not just do `startActivity(new Intent(CurrentClass.this, ClassWhereToGo.class));` rather than have a separate helper class. Upvoted anyway, since you answered the question as asked.

Comment: Thanks for the help. 
Although "public class Helper...." is not working like that. I get an error at line
`startActivity(explicitIntent);`
since the class is not an Android view-class.
if I change the class to
`public class Helper extends Activity`
and remove the `static` from the method then it works. Just not sure if this is the "official" and "proper" way how to do it.

Comment: @user753827: startActivity is a member of context. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly like this!